# How to combine List elements in between certain elements

Tags: c#, string, parsing, input, split

I have an input string: `//CommandName "Hello this World" (5, 4, 3)`

I use Split to get all entries from this input and I store it all in the list.

```
List<String> s = input.Split().ToList();
```

How can I combine all elements that are in between elements that starts and ends with ' " '?

Also the same for the vector coordinates? e.g. `(2, 5, 8)`. 
So combine all elements that are in between elements that starts with `(` and ends with  `)`.

Should I be using Regex for this?

Comment: Please tag a language.

Comment: Hey, sorry I am working with c#. I updated the question specifying it

Comment: Is it legal to have parenthesis within a string parameter, `"Hello (test) example"`, (I assume it would be), and is it legal to have quotes within parentheses, `("5", "6", "7")`?

Comment: i would choose arrays for this.You can iterate over characters and collect/combine them into another array or list .This gives you the ability of controlling indexes of
 characters.

Comment: A regex with capture groups would probably work for this

Comment: For a parentheses within quotes it is okay, but for quotes within parentheses no because I want to treat that entry as a vector. So just get integers or Singles between parentheses. I will look into capture groups, tho I never used it before. Thanks!

Comment: Also, will you want the ability to escape special characters in the string, e.g. what if you want your string to include a quote?

Comment: After I get the string within the quotes I add it into a list of strings. If a quote is inside the string so like `"Hello " This World"` I will pretty much handle this as invalid input. And will return false meaning that it could not parse the input correctly. If there are multiple strings in the input, e.g. `"Hello This" "World"` I stored them separately into the list of strings. Or at least something like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A real basic example with a regex:

```
var pattern = new Regex("([^ ]+) \"([^\"]+)\" \\(([^)]+)\\)");
var match = pattern.Match("command \"string\" (0, 1, 2)");
var command = match.Groups[1];
var text = match.Groups[2];
var location = match.Groups[3];

Console.WriteLine(command);
Console.WriteLine(text);
Console.WriteLine(location);
```

This example assumes that you will always have the same number of parameters, of the same type, and it doesn't handle including quotes within a string, but it gives you an idea of how you might implement this with a regex.

**An explanation of the regex**

```
(?<command>[^ ]+)                                  The first sequence of characters up to a space
( (?<parameter>...))*                              Zero or more parameters, separated by a space
```

The expression of the `parameter` capture group is any of the following:

```
(?<boolean>true|false)                             A boolean literal
(?<integer>[+-]?[0-9][0-9]*)                       An integer literal
(?<float>[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)   A floating point literal
(?<string>\"[^\"]+\")                              A string literal
(?<vector>\\([^)]+\\))                             A vector literal
```

Since you managed to add your own expressions for integer and float, I assume you understand how each of the individual regexes match their respective parts. It just looks a little daunting once you combine all those expressions together with a pipe symbol in between.

Comment: Thanks! This would not truly work cause the input might be different e.g.`//CommandName "Some Text" 5 false (1, 2, 3)`. There also might be different entries like a boolean or just an integer or a single and so on and all in different order. So I'm wondering if there is a pattern that would find all matches that are separated by the space and would ignore spaces in between characters like quote marks or parentheses? I'm not so good with Regex patterns tho. Just not long ago started looking into Regex in general.

Comment: Yeah you can have a pattern to match parameters of all the different types, and you can repeatedly capture that pattern (this can be done all in one regex). Then in your code, you'd have to check which group it matched to determine how you should parse it.

Comment: E.g. `"(?<command>[^ ]+)( (?<parameter>(?<boolean>true|false)|(?<string>\"[^\"]+\")|(?<vector>\\([^)]+\\))))*"`. I've named the capture groups for easier access, so instead of referring by index, you can call `match.Groups["command"]`, etc. To iterate over the parameters, `foreach (var capture in match.Groups["parameter"].Captures)`

Comment: Your example works great! Thank you :) I added couple of more data types, the integer (`"(?<integer>[+-]?[0-9][0-9]*)"`) and the floating-point, tho I have some issues with the float. `"(?<float>[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)"` It gives me an error which says `Unrecognized escape sequence` The error happens with this `\.` in the pattern. As a total noob when it comes to Regex I am a bit confused by this whole thing. Is this performance wise a good option?

Comment: This is how the entire pattern looks like at the moment: `var pattern = new Regex("(?<command>[^ ]+)( (?<parameter>(?<boolean>true|false)|(?<integer>[+-]?[0-9][0-9]*)|(?<float>[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?)|(?<string>\"[^\"]+\")|(?<vector>\\([^)]+\\))))*");` It looks a bit scary when I don't understand half of it :p